# Uncaught ReferenceError: sort is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm probably missing something because I'm getting this error and tried to google similar examples or solutions to this error, but no luck.

I have this two functions inside one single js and error is happening inside innerHTML code.

```
// ($p) is the selected page number. it will be generated when a user clicks a button
function sort($p) {
    /* create ($rows) a variable to hold the group of rows
    ** to be displayed on the selected page,
    ** ($s) the start point .. the first row in each page, Do The Math
    */
    var $rows = $th, $s = (($n * $p) - $n);
    for ($i = $s; $i < ($s + $n) && $i < $tr.length; $i++)
        $rows += $tr[$i];

    // now the table has a processed group of rows ..
    $table.innerHTML = $rows;
    // create the pagination buttons
    document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = pageButtons($pageCount, $p);
    // CSS Stuff
    document.getElementById("id" + $p).setAttribute("class", "active");
};

// ($pCount) : number of pages,($cur) : current page, the selected one ..
function pageButtons($pCount, $cur) {
    /* this variables will disable the "Prev" button on 1st page
    and "next" button on the last one */
    var $prevDis = ($cur == 1) ? "disabled" : "",
        $nextDis = ($cur == $pCount) ? "disabled" : "",
        /* this ($buttons) will hold every single button needed
        ** it will creates each button and sets the onclick attribute
        ** to the "sort" function with a special ($p) number..
        */
        $buttons = "<input type='button' value='&lt;&lt; Prev' onclick='sort(" + ($cur - 1) + ");' " + $prevDis + ">";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pCount; $i++)
        $buttons += "<input type='button' id='id" + $i + "'value='" + $i + "' onclick='sort(" + $i + ");'>";
    $buttons += "<input type='button' value='Next &gt;&gt;' onclick='sort(" + ($cur + 1) + ");' " + $nextDis + ">";
    return $buttons;
}
```

Comment: which error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these functions are inside of a [Javascript closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), `sort` will not be accessible on the global level. And since you are building the elements using pure HTML, they will only be able to access global variables.

You will need to either export sort into the global context with the statement `window.sort = sort;`. Or better, don't build your HTML directly; create the buttons and add onclick events to them, as such:\

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.addEventListener("click", function() {
    sort(1);
});
```

Comment: where is the closure?

Comment: "I have this two functions **inside one single js** and error is happening..."